# Python- Can you create a list that stores the names of other variables?

Tags: python, list

I want to read in a file that contains a variable name that is defined in my code i.e. (Variable1 = 5 and Variable2 = 6).

For example, my file may look something like this:

```
Variable1
Variable2
```

I can read those names into a list (lets call it input_list)

Now I want to use the value of that variable in another function ie:

```
add(input_list[0], input_list[1])
```

However, it is reading the input as strings Variable1 and Variable2, but I want it to read in the values as ints of 5 and 6)

I know this sounds confusing, but hopefully someone can understand what I am trying to do (if it is even possible)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I don't think that is a good duplicate.  While it maybe a better solution to the OP's problem (whatever that is), it is not a duplicate to the question.

Comment: You can cast variables to int `map(int, input_list)`

Comment: @COLDSPEED I'm not sure the question you marked as duplicate is the same thing. Although I could probably use a dictionaries, I don't think that would be efficient at all, as I am grabbing the variable declarations from yet another file

Comment: @Nikitka Thanks for the suggestion but casting won't work in this case either has input_list will contain "Variable1" and "Variable2"

Comment: @user3326870 Do you have variable names in the file? If so, you can get variable value like this `eval(input_list[0])`

Comment: @Nikitka Yes! This was exactly what I was looking for Thank You!!